# constraint layout gone wrong, placing textview wrong on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So i started with android studio, and it hit me in the face with the constraint layout. At first i was ....help... But after it it seemed very nice and after reading a bit, about it i felt i should try out.
Now i had done my design and try to run it on my phone and i got a diffrent layout then it should be.

I use a lg5 with android 7.0, also i added a virtual device with the specs of lg5 with both android 7.1/7.0 and that seems to work out right.

I tried looking on google but couldnt find any answers or a hint that could help me.
I asked help at the reddit android-dev on discord, but they dont know either, other then i should use relative layout. But i want to know first what i am doing wrong.

could someone help me with what im missing, or did wrong?

the button and fields under "dont have an account yet?"working and are hiding(invisible) like they should be.

**edit** still hoping someone would see what i did wrong so i can learn for in the future :)

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cyberdog.mtgcollection.Login">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etvLoginNameDCI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name/DCI Number"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etvLoginPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etvLoginPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cbLoginRememberMe" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbLoginRememberMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="Remeber me"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnLoginLogin"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.328" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoginLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Log in"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvRegisterAlreadyRegister" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegisterAlreadyRegister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Dont have a n account yet?"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etvRegisterNameDCI" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etvRegisterNameDCI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name/DCI"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etvRegisterEmail"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etvRegisterEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etvRegisterPassword"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etvRegisterPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnRegisterRegister"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegisterRegister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: How it looks on phone]

[image: the design layout]

Comment: @Rotwang isnt this an android studio thing? i believe the constraint was specificly made for android studio?

Comment: No. It's made for **Android**. Android Studio is only an **IDE**. Which is **irrelevant**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are hiding your views with `visibility="invisible"` which takes space and pushes your views up out of the screen. Try using `visibility="gone"`.

Comment: why does it push them out of the view? you can see how they are located, they are under the textview with enough room. so how can they push them out of the screen?

Comment: You can try changing them to be visible always and see how it is actually taking space on the screen. The DPI/font-size seems to vary a lot on your preview screen and the actual device.

Comment: this was not it, like i thought the scren stays the same but with those views visible. still thanks for looking at it :)

Comment: When you change it to `gone` the screen stays the same with those views visible? It should have hidden all of the views and made your visible views come down within the screen limits.

Comment: Yup with gone it does work till they get visible again but it also messes up the start screen as everything goes down alot, instead of they are at the top they are at the bottom(the login parts) and after clicking the "link" it will result again in te wrong screen layout.

Comment: also why does it work with the virtual machines, but not on the real machine, they got the same dimensions...

Comment: Dimensions may be the same, but DPI seems to be different. The issue is because the constraints are not exactly what they should be. Will update my answer to change the constraints that fulfil your requirements.

Comment: Do you want it to scroll on smaller displays?

Comment: Nope, and if I need to I can always add a scroll view later, but for now it's  not needed.

Comment: You say it's not needed with just one device in mind, but your layout doesn't even fit on a Nexus 4 screen.

Comment: That's because for now it's targeting a lg g5 device, and maybe it will chance to other devices in the future.

Comment: I don't know, my personal style of working is to make the UI dynamic and make it support all screens even if I target the app to be used just by me on a single device.

Comment: The issue particularly seems to be with the device definition you added. The display is not just about resolution, DPI needs to be considered. As your screenshots show, the device definition in your Android Studio seems to have quite lower DPI compared to your actual device.

Comment: and how do i change that? and i thought that constraint layout did make it dynamic?

Comment: also i have added the dpi of 554(ppi) so that should not be different from actual and virtual device. **Edit:** seems i was wrong i cannot edit the dpi/ppi... going to search that on google.

Comment: Checked my dpi and it's the same as its in the specs online. Will check the dpi of the virtual devices when I'm home.

Comment: finally got myself time to install google app on the virtual device but i can not install apps from there to the device.. not sure why not. so still cannot test the dpi there :S

Comment: The latest version of emulators with Google APIs have Google Play Store pre-installed.

Comment: Well not on my emulators it seems.. And I have selected Google api

Comment: somehow android studio adding a device function doesnt work when you put in the specifications of the lg 5, now im using pixel xl(2 inch more) and changed my display on the device to smaller icons. (this also helped)